# Could I add an association based on another association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My User model looks like:

```
User
   habtm  :Roles


Role
   habtm  :Users


RoleExtension
   belongs_to  :Role
```

mysql tables:

```
users
  id
  ..


roles
  id
  ..

roles_users
  user_id
  role_id

role_extensions
  id
  role_id
  feature_id
  ..
  ..
```

Now everything seems to be working fine so far.

**Now I want the User model to have a collection of RoleExtensions, based on the habtm Roles collection.**

example:

```
user = User.find(1)
user.Roles  (returns roles with id's of 1,2,3)
```

So I want:

```
user.RoleExtensions
```

to return all Role extensions that have role_id in (1,2,3)

Comment: user.Role[0].RoleExtensions works, but I want ALL RoleExtensions not just the role extension for a particular role.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally you'd use a [`has_many, :through`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has_many-through-association) association, but that doesn't apply to `has_and_belongs_to_many` relations.

So, instead, in your User model:

```
def role_extensions
  return roles.inject([]) do |array, role|
    role.role_extensions do |re|
      array.include?(re) ? array << re : array
    end
  end
end
```

Then `my_user.role_extensions` should return an array of all role extensions belonging to all the user's roles.

*Note: I haven't tested this, but it should work*

**UPDATE**: I like this better

```
def role_extensions
  return roles.inject([]) { |array, role| array << role.role_extensions }.flatten!.uniq
end
```

Comment: ok well actually the previous question you answered for me answered it (i did it that way instead), but I was hoping I was doing something wrong in my associations as I wanted to figure this out!

Answer (score 0):

```
user = User.find(1)
RoleExtension.find(:all, :conditions => ["role_id IN (?)", user.role_ids])
```

Otherwise you can use nested joins.

Comment: How could I make this an associated in user though?  how to get role_ids?  i'm new to this!

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
# Fetch user object
user = User.first

# If you want roles of that user try this
roles = user.roles

# You can map all the role extensions of that user by
role_extensions = user.roles.map(&:role_extensions).uniq
```

Be aware that this will be extremely slow for large number of roles. In that case better write your own query method. Something like

```
role_extensions = RoleExtension.where("role_id in (?)", user.role_ids).all
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@user.role_extensions.where(:joins => :roles)
```

Comment: would it be @user.RoleExtensions or @user.role_extensions, confused?