# How to create a lazy loaded property in Ruby for a Model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to create a lazy-loaded property that returns a collection on a Model, how do I do this?

I don't want to create an association for this.

So I want it to return a collection, if the collection hasn't been initialized yet then hit the database, return the rows, then initialize it.

If it get's run once, then no need to run it again since the next page request will start things over.

Comment: Why would you want to do it this way? This is precisely what an association is for.

Comment: @tadman b/c its not working for me as of yet, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5215836/could-i-add-an-association-based-on-another-association

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Add an instance attribute (e.g. `@my_attribute`)

And then define

```
def my_attribute
  @my_attribute ||= initialize_my_attribute
end
```

(Note: `initialize_my_attribute` is a function/method you've implemented that will load the value you want.)

How this works: the attribute starts out with a `nil` value (we haven't assigned anything to it). The object instance can't access it directly, because we haven't defined an attribute accessor on it. Instead we have a method that has the exact same name as the attribute, so that when you call `my_object.my_attribute` it looks exactly as if you're accessing the attribute when you're actually calling the object instance's method.

What happens in the method? The `||=` short hand is equivalent to

```
@my_attribute = (@my_attribute || initialize_my_attribute)
```

So if `@my_attribute` already has value, that value is returned. Otherwise, `@my_attribute` gets a value assigned (and then returned). In other words: the value will be loaded in `@my_attribute` the first time it is accessed (and only the first time).

And voila! Lazy loading.

Comment: Actually, `||=` is a shortcut for `@my_attribute = (@my_attribute || initialize_my_attribute)` which has a slightly different behavior than your example regarding falsy non-nil values.

Answer (score 0):

Associated properties are lazy-loaded by default. Check your logs so see that queries to the database are only done if the property is accessed.

I ran into this issue too. And after I implemented my self-made lazy-loading functions I realised that they were meaningless. By adding lazy-loaders like described above, you add a lazy-loader to the internal lazy-loader which makes things slower in terms of performance without adding any value.