# I have a Roles association, need a contains method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a User model that has a Roles collection.

The Roles collection has columns like:

```
id, name, ....
```

I am now looping through another collection, and I would to create a new collection if the role_id's match, so:

```
SomeOtherCollection.each do |i|

@blah << i  if self.Roles.contains i.role_id

end
```

Contains doesn't exist, how can I do this?

The faster method the better since this will happen allot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `Role` is an ActiveRecord model and you mean to call `self.roles`, not `self.Roles`, and you're using Rails 3:

```
SomeOtherCollection.each do |i|
  @blah << i  if self.roles.where(:role_id => i.role_id).count > 0
end
```

Side note: [cancan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan) is a really great authorization gem that you might find useful.

Comment: I am doing self.Roles, what's the difference?  In my User.rb I have:  has_many :Roles    its upper case.

Comment: It may not make a difference, but it should be lowercase in both locations.

Comment: I see, it isn't working with lower case, I probably have to change my assocations, i hate uppercase anyhow thanks man!

Comment: I am really stuck on this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5215836/could-i-add-an-association-based-on-another-association if you can help!

Comment: error: NoMethodError: You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!
You might have expected an instance of Array.
The error occurred while evaluating nil.<<

Comment: I don't get it, which object is nil, the @blah?

Comment: It looks like it is, sorry at first I thought something else was causing it. Make sure `@blah` is initialized to an array first (e.g. `@blah ||= []`)

Comment: in my code @blah is the same name as the method that calls this i.e.: def blah  SomeOtherColl..... end

Comment: actually I had to do return @blah in the method, otherwise it was returning SomeOtherCollection.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your collection includes `Enumerable` (e.g. is an `Array`, etc), you can use [`any?`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Enumerable.html#M001500), which returns true if *any* iteration of the block returns true:

```
@blah << i if self.Roles.any? { |role| role.id == i.role_id }
```

If your user class is set up like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # some stuff
  has_many :roles
end
```

and the method you're using is somewhere in the `User` class, you probably want something like this:

```
SomeOtherCollection.each do |i|
  @blah << i if self.roles.any? { |role| role.id == i.role_id }
end
```

Comment: so every active record supports enumerable and is an array?

Comment: If you're using ActiveRecord associations, e.g. your class User `has_many :roles`, then yes, `user.roles` is an Array.

Comment: so self.Roles.include? i.role_id will match if Roles.id = i.role_id (for all the entries in Roles) right?

Comment: Except it's an array of objects.

Comment: ok it won't work, since the 'SomeOtherCollection' doesn't have the same objcts as self.roles...i just have to make sure self.roles matches in terms of self.role.id == SomeOtherCollection[0].role_id (for all occurances of self.role.id)

Comment: same issue as with Andrews: NoMethodError: You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!
You might have expected an instance of Array.
The error occurred while evaluating nil.<<

Comment: Is that happening on the line that calls `self.roles.any?`? If so, that means that `self.roles` is nil (probably a problem with your associations).

Comment: no in rails console u.roles is fine, it seems to be the @blah << i part.  should @blah be declared elsewhere? getter/setter?

Answer (score 0):

`include?` is the method you want

http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.html#M000265

And a more rubyish way to do what you want is:

```
@blah = some_collection.select { |i| self.Roles.include? i.role_id }
```